# Why isn't my color binding working

Tags: wpf

I have a label in xaml

```
<Label Content="This is a test"
               Foreground="{Binding Path=TextColor, Converter={StaticResource ResourceKey=colorConverter}}" />
```

in my view model I have the property

```
public string TextColor
{
    get{ return "00FFFF"; }
}
```

and for my color converter I have the class

```
 public class ColorConverter : IValueConverter
  {
    #region IValueConverter Members

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        string color = (string)value;
        if (!color.Substring(0, 1).Equals("#"))
        { color = color.Insert(0, "#"); }

        Color result = (Color)System.Windows.Media.ColorConverter.ConvertFromString(color);
        return result;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        Color c = (Color)value;
        return string.Format("#{0}{1}{2}", c.R.ToString("x2"), c.G.ToString("x2"), c.B.ToString("x2"));
    }

    #endregion
}
```

The color of the text is blac instead of the blue green it is supposed to be.
when I step through it, the Convert method appears to return the correct color. I'm not sure where else to look to figure this out.

Comment: Try return SolidColorBrush instead of Color.

Comment: Can i ask why are you using a converter for a string value instead of having the property of your viewmodel defined directly as returning a "Color" value? Something like "public Color myColor {get;set;}"

Comment: Why in this case implement converter? Why not just set the string as `#00FFFF`, and TypeConverter automatically converts it into color. Besides converters do not always play well with the performance, you should avoid them when you can do without it.

Comment: @MaratKhasanov that worked any idea why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will actually work if you just update the converter to return the "formatted" string, instead of trying to cast it to a `Color` object.

```
   public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        string color = (string)value;
        if (!color.Substring(0, 1).Equals("#"))
        { 
            color = color.Insert(0, "#"); 
        }
        return color ;
    }
```

Though as suggested, there should be no point of having a converter just to add a '#'. This could be done using StringFormat as well (within the binding).. Or just do the conversion inside the property if you really need it.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know that you could just use the string.